# How to layout ? Use Relative Layout or Linear Layout?

Tags: android

I'm struggling with an Android layout here, this seems like it should be so simple, but no joy, a simple linear layout results in the image shown:

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="100dp">
    <TextView
        android:text="Last Game"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:background="#003300" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#ffffff">
        <ImageView
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_gallery"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:layout_height="80dp" />
        <TextView
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:text="WR"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:paddingRight="5dp" />
        <View
            android:background="#000000"
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:id="@+id/view1"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
        <TextView
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:text="LR"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp" />
        <ImageView
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_gallery"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_height="80dp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

What I want, is the Left image to be at the left margin (left justified)
The Right image at the right margin (right justified)
the Vertical bar to always be centered
And the WR to be right justified close to the center
And the LR to be left justified close to the center.

Should I use Relative Layout?

Comment: LinearLayout with five Views and weight, I'd say?

Comment: Keep both of them in different Linear Layout. Set padding according to your need and **android:gravity="left"** and **right** according to your need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would. You can use

```
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
```

and

```
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
```

for the images, respecitvely. Then use

```
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
```

for your line and

```
android:layout_toLeftOf="id"  // enter id of line
```

and

```
android:layout_toRightOf="id" // enter id of line
```

to place your `TextView`s on either side of the line and add `padding` as needed

Comment: I wish Android used the springs model like Qt does, I can make that do anything.

Comment: `RelativeLayout` is actually very versatile and easy to use/modify once you get the hang of it, IMHO. It just takes a little playing with to get comfortable and they can be much more efficient by removing nested `LinearLayout`s

Answer (score 1):

You need FrameLayout, that suits your requirement best
Use below layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          android:background="#ffffff"
          android:minWidth="25px"
          android:minHeight="100dp">
<TextView
        android:text="Last Game"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:background="#003300" />
<FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#ffffff">
    <ImageView
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_gallery"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:layout_height="80dp" />
    <TextView
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:text="WR"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
            />
    <View
            android:background="#000000"
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:id="@+id/view1"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
    <TextView
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:text="LR"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
            />
    <ImageView
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_gallery"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_height="80dp" />
</FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

RelativeLayout.  Make the left image layout_alignParentLeft=true.  Make the center line layout_centerHorizontal=true.  Make the WR layout_align_toLeftOf="id of line" and make have gravity="right".  Repeat on the other side with opposite directions.