# Prefer Linear Layout or Relative Layout in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout

I am writing an application with certain number of activities. How do we determine whether an activity needs a linear layout or a relative layout?

Comment: Read [this](http://www.androidhive.info/2011/07/android-layouts-linear-layout-relative-layout-and-table-layout/).

Comment: this has been asked too many times before

Comment: that link really helps RKN :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to layout ? Use Relative Layout or Linear Layout?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15882035/how-to-layout-use-relative-layout-or-linear-layout)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Its generally preferred to use relative layout if you have got a lot of nesting in your application because your XML is exploded in to source code and performance issues arise if you have got lot of nested linear layouts. If your application has minimal design and less nesting you can go for a linear layout.

Answer (score 0):

> How do we determine whether an activity needs a linear layout or a
>   relative layout?

It's a personal preference for most cases. You should however try to stick to `RelativeLayout`, if you are using multiple nested `LinearLayouts` since those can drop your performance noticeably.

Answer (score 0):

**LinearLayout**

The LinearLayout is the most simple layout available in Android. A LinearLayout organizes layout components in a linear fashion horizontally or vertically. Create a new Android project TestBasicLayout in Eclipse to develop in.

**RelativeLayout**

The RelativeLayout Organizes layout components in relation to each other. This provides more flexibility of component positioning than LinearLayouts..the RelativeLayout doesn't need the orientation attribute. When using a RelativeLayout all elements should have an ID. This ID will be referenced in the placement attributes.

Comment: u r welcome..if u got ur answer then dont forget to mark my answer as the correcr answer.